# Adding a unique number to each item returned by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using ng-repeat, I want to print out all the items in my array, how would I attach a unique number to each item? Like so:

```
1. Item One
2. Item Two
3. Item Three
4. Item Four....
```

So far I have this...

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>UNIQUE NUMBER</span>          
    <span>{{item}}</span>
</li>
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs for ng-repeat...

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in the Angular docs of all places... thanks to Stewie

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span>{{$index + 1}}</span>          
    <span>{{item}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) CSS property of the `li` items. Declare this in CSS:

```
li {
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

Using programming for this task is not the best idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/6MnGe/